# Unity Building "failed": UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono

Basically I am building my project in random locations and the project folder and nothing is working so I was wondering if it was something else. I am getting these errors:

```
Error 1: Error building Player: DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory '/Shaders/Water' not found.

Error 2: Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Error 3: UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0020e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:181 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:88 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Error 4: DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory '/Shaders/Water' not found.
System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:514)
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:308)
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Directory.cs:303)
UltimateWater.Editors.EditorShaderCollectionBuilder.CleanUpUnusedShaders () (at Assets/Ultimate Water System v1.0.0/Scripts/Editor/EditorShaderCollectionBuilder.cs:54)
UltimateWater.Editors.WaterShadersCleanupTask.OnWillSaveAssets (System.String[] paths) (at Assets/Ultimate Water System v1.0.0/Scripts/Editor/EditorShaderCollectionBuilder.cs:140)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
UnityEditor.AssetModificationProcessorInternal.OnWillSaveAssets (System.String[] assets, System.String[]& assetsThatShouldBeSaved, System.String[]& assetsThatShouldBeReverted, Int32 explicitlySaveAsset) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssetModificationProcessor.cs:147)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

The project isn't building.

Comment: With a question like this you kind of need to show the source code and where it is throwing the error. With that being said, error 1 is telling you that the folder /Shaders/Water doesn't exist in the current context. Is that folder in the right place?

Comment: @TannerH agreed, we don't have nearly enough information to help with this one.

Comment: I think I fixed it by deleting the assets: UBER and Ultimate Water System.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but not exactly this.
You can try to change the API compatibility level under Project Settings > Player.

While searching for the solution, I found that people were switching to.Net2, but mine was .Net2 by default, so I switched to .Net 4.x and it builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Build System from Gradle to Internal fixed the problem for me. See the snapshot below.

[image: snapshot of the Build Setting]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a problem with the Unity Monetization plugin, I reinstalled it and now everything works

Answer (score 0):

finally i find it solition just follow steps.

1. open unity hub
2. go to installs
3. find your on work unity version
4. click add modules
5. end add Windows Build Support (IL2CCP)
6. end build again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it notified me that the a file path was missing:

> tundra: error: Failed to open file "[...]/Library/Il2cppBuildCache/iOS/buildstate/tundra.log.json" for structured logging

I created the path and the file manually, and then it worked.